# How to make TextInputLayout hint asterisk red for required fields

Tags: android, android-edittext, material-design, android-textinputlayout

Is it possible to make just the asterisk in the hint red when using a TextInputLayout from the design support library? I have seen information on styling the entire hint, but this is a little more complex since only the * should be red, not the whole message.

The Material Design example shows this, but the design library doesn't seem to have any option to style it this way using a TextInputLayout and EditText.

Reference:
https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-required-fields

Example (the top, with focus, has the red asterisk; the bottom without focus does not have a red asterisk):

[image: Example of hint text with red asterisk]

I looked into setting the hint to a SpannableString (see here [How to get a red asterisk in a <string> entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456588/how-to-get-a-red-asterisk-in-a-string-entry)) in an OnFocusChangeListener (see here [Having the mandatory symbol to the edit text (red color asterisk) which is inside the textinputlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33414066/having-the-mandatory-symbol-to-the-edit-text-red-color-asterisk-which-is-insid)), but the hint is a CharSequence.

Is there any way to do this without extending TextInputLayout?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: No, I am currently planning to leave it as-is until the design library supports the red asterisk.

Comment: As of 09/09/2017, the material design guidelines as on this page [here](https://material.io/guidelines/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-layout) doesn't have a red color asterix, the below image from the page shows the edittext focused and unfocused states. [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCdxn.png)

Comment: When I use this, the bar's don't show up for my under the EditText. Did you do anything special to make it show up?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: I edited my solution with a simple way to make the asterisk red: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46450127/4433326

Answer (score 31):

You can use the Material Components Library.
Starting from the [**`1.2.0-alpha05`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/7822b6d05e7fe890a45fe688e3dbbaf2c76d618a) you can format the hint text.

For example you can just use something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:hint="@string/hint_test"
    ...>
```

with:

```
<string name="hint_test">Legal name <font color='#FF0000'>*</font></string>
```

[image][image]

Comment: This should be accepted as answer. works as expected. thanks a lot

Comment: for me this worked - <string name="hint_test">Legal name <font color='#FF0000'>*</font></string>

Comment: I had to change `fgcolor` with `color` and it worked for me

Comment: how to programmatically add the asterisk without placing it manually in resource file?

Answer (score 23):

Material Design specify an asterisk for the required fields that is part of the hint text, and of the same color (not in red like you showed in your question).

In Kotlin this is really simple:

1.Define this extension method:

```
fun TextInputLayout.markRequired() {
    hint = "$hint *"
}
```

2.Use it:

```
input_first_name.markRequired()
```

If you still want the asterisk red, despite being discouraged by Material Design guidelines, you can use AndroidX Core KTX that way:

```
fun TextInputLayout.markRequiredInRed() {
    hint = buildSpannedString {
        append(hint)
        color(Color.RED) { append(" *") } // Mind the space prefix.
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi please give me your ans android  using java. i will require this type of TextInputLayout using.

Comment: @mujjuraja It's much uglier in Java, I recommend you [try.kotl.in](https://try.kotl.in), but here's what you can do: `inputFirstName.setHint(inputFirstName.getHint() + " *")`

Comment: for TextInputLayout, the star shows, but it is not red for me. :(

Comment: Maybe they disabled changing the text color altogether in a recent version.

Answer (score 3):

Could you be adding a spanned string From Html?

```
   String grey = "Legal first name*";
   Spanned redStar;
   String html = "<string style="color:grey;">Legal first name<span style="color:red;">*</span></string>";

   if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
   redStar = Html.fromHtml(html,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
   } else {
   redStar = Html.fromHtml(html);
   }
```

And change the hint upon focus.

```
   textInput.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
   public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if (hasFocus)
        myEditText.setHint(redStar.toString);
    else
        myEditText.setHint(grey);
}
```

Comment: it work programmatically, just need to wrap into function

Answer (score 2):

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

change you theme colorAccent and see

Comment: See [the material example](https://material.google.com/style/color.html#color-color-schemes), there is a chapter on this. You should add those information in your answer. But this might change more things than expected.

Answer (score 0):

Change TextInputLayout hint by adding a postfix wrapped in html:

```
public void setRequired(boolean required) {

  componentField.setHint(TextUtils.concat(
      componentField.getHint(),
      Html.fromHtml(getContext().getString(
          R.string.required_asterisk))));
}
```

Asterisk code should be stored in android strings.xml for correct escaping:

```
<string name = "required_asterisk"><![CDATA[<font color=\'#cc0029\'>&nbsp*</font>]]></string>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
textinputlayout.setHint(Html.fromHtml("Project Title <font color =\"#cc0029\" >*</font>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's set the two text first, one is with asterisk and another without.

```
 val enterEmailHint = "Enter your email <font color=\"#FF0000\">*</font>"
 val enterEmailNormal = "Enter your email"
```

Then we need to add focus changed listener to the textInputEditText (not the TextInputLayout). When the editText is in focus, it'll show the asterisk in red color, otherwise no astericks.

```
binding.emailEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
    if (hasFocus) {
        binding.emailTextInputLayout.hint =
            Html.fromHtml(enterEmailHint, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
    } else {
        binding.emailTextInputLayout.hint = enterEmailNormal
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes Its possible , because i am doing same thing in my current application. and for focus and unfocus you have to do some logic to remove asterisk.

```
String mm = "Legal first name";
Spannable WordtoSpan = new SpannableString(mm);
WordtoSpan.setSpan(
        new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#e62e6c")), 
        16, 
        mm.length(), 
        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
WordtoSpan.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.9f), 16, mm.length(), 0);
view.setText(WordtoSpan);
```

Comment: nope can't do it with an TextInputLayout: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=197889

Answer (score -1):

I have been through the same process and it worked for me

```
 TextView text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.name_textview);

 SpannableStringBuilder builder1 = setStarToLabel("Name");

 text.setText(builder1);

  @NonNull
private SpannableStringBuilder setStarToLabel(String text) {
    String simple = text;
    String colored = "*";
    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    builder.append(simple);
    int start = builder.length();
    builder.append(colored);
    int end = builder.length();
    builder.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return builder;
}
```

Comment: This logic is applied to TextView not the TextInputLayout that is required